# Downloading yaml from JFrog repository

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, artifactory

We have a swagger yaml published on Jfrog repositories and want to download that using Gradle as compile-time dependency.

Artifact Structure.

```
19.9.0.0-1-SNAPSHOT
    - resource-19.9.0.0-1-20210805.034659-153.yaml
    - resource-19.9.0.0-1-20210805.034659-153.module
    - resource-19.9.0.0-1-20210805.034659-153.pom
    - resource-19.9.0.0-1-20210805.034659-153.jar
    - resource-19.9.0.0-1-20210805.153153-154.yaml
    - resource-19.9.0.0-1-20210805.153153-154.module
    - resource-19.9.0.0-1-20210805.153153-154.pom
    - resource-19.9.0.0-1-20210805.153153-154.jar
```

I tried doing something like this. Which does not seem to work.

```
compile(group: 'com.myorg.myproject', name: 'resource', version: '19.9.0.0-1-SNAPSHOT', ext: 'yaml')
```

There is no way to know the version beforehand, so gradle download could not help.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the version to `latest.integration` to download the latest artifact's version:

```
compile(group: 'com.myorg.myproject', name: 'resource', version: 'latest.integration', ext: 'yaml')
```

`latest.integration` should resolve the latest artifact version available, no matter if it is a snapshot or a release. If you want the latest release, for example, use `latest.release`.

For more information see [Declaring Versions and Ranges](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/single_versions.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, The `latest.integration` will always pull latest version.  If you see `19.9.` and `20.0` are different release versions maintained. `compile(group: 'com.myorg.myproject', name: 'resource', version: 'latest.integration', ext: 'yaml')`, will pull the 20.0 version from artifactory, Is there a way to make it pull from `19.9` latest?

Comment: Yes. Try using version `19.9.+`.